# Angular ng-include in Jade.

Tags: angularjs, express, pug, angularjs-ng-include

I'm trying to include a header, using ng-include from Angular into my Jade template:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
        meta(charset='UTF-8')
        meta(name='fragment', content='!')
        base(href='/')
        title Node Express Angular
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/syle.css')
    body(ng-app='myApp')
        ng-include(src='\'/partials/header.jade\'')
        div.container
            div.jumbotron.text-center
                h1 Home Page
                p This page is a draft in progress
        script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.15/angular.min.js')
        script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js')
        script(src='/js/app.js')
```

The text in header.jade is the following:

```
nav.navbar.navbar-inverse(role='navigation')
ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-header
    li
        a(src='/home', class='navbar-brand') Home
    li
        a(src='/about') About
    li
        a(src='/login') Login
    li
        a(src='/register') Register
```

I have tried both `ng-include(src='\'/partials/header.jade\'')` and `div(ng-include='\'/partials/header.jade\'')`

In the Chrome developer console, the first one results in `<!--ng-Include: undefined -->` and the second: `<!-- ng-Include: '/partials/header.jade' -->`

Any clues?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why you're using Angular's `ng-include` instead of Jade's own include mechanism?

```
body(ng-app='myApp')
    include partials/header
```

Reference form the the [Jade docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#includes).

Comment: Thx, this worked. No, there wasn't any specific reason, apart from trying to combine Jade and Angular. Not very straightforward what should handle what.

Comment: Ok, great. This is how we're including partials in my current project and I was just wondering if this lacks something you were after. (That "is there a specific reason" looks a bit crude to my own eye now...)

Comment: No worries, there are many things that both Jade or Angular can do, I'm struggling separating which ones are best for each purpose.

Comment: I like this solution because it bypasses the scope problems you get when you use `ng-include`.

Comment: I think it's also more idiomatic when the part to be included is static content and contains no Angular logic.

Answer (score 1):

I created an Angular directive to be rendered by JADE and then compiled by Angular to the given scope.... and it works!

btw,I'm using client-side Jade for browsers, the CDN is available **[here](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jade)**

for e.g:

html:

```
<ng-include src="'MyPageWithJadeScript.html'"></ng-include>
```

MyPageWithJadeScript.html:

```
<jade>tag#id.class jade text</jade>
```

angular:

```
app
.directive('jade',function($compile){
return{
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element){
      element
        .after(
          $compile(
            jade
            .render(
                element.html(),
                {pretty:'\t'}
            )
          )(scope)
        )
        .remove();
    }
};
});
```

Hope you find this useful

Answer (score 0):

Refer to official doc [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude), using the code below

`div(ng-include="'partials/header.jade'")`

If you want to use ngInclude directive directly, use

`ng-include(src="'partials/header.jade'")`

Comment: I have tried both and both don't render the content of my file header.jade. I did check before hand that the content of my jade file was valid.

Comment: How about removing `base(href='/')` ?

Comment: Have you checked your template engine? Maybe you can try `div(ng-include="'partials/header.html'")`

Comment: I had already tried this, i have created a header.html, and obviously converted it from jade to html. Didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Using express, I have the file user-description.jade inside of the views/ folder and to include it in another jade file I simple use the following expression:

```
div
  include user-description.jade
```

[Jade docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/) has other samples.